# Decode returning multiple rows

Tags: decode

I have a business case where in a table I may have a specific value or it will have value as 'ALL'. While I query the table if particular input matches I need that particular record. If its not matching then entry with ALL should be considered and returned.

Here is the case that you have try at your end to replicate the issues.

```
CREATE TABLE lookup_value (
 country             VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
 department               VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
 problem_code     VARCHAR2(30),
 disposition                 VARCHAR2(30));

INSERT INTO lookup_value VALUES ('US','SALES','P0044','EXCHANGE')

INSERT INTO lookup_value VALUES ('US','SALES','ALL','EXCHANGE')

INSERT INTO lookup_value VALUES ('US','SALES','P0020','ALL')

INSERT INTO lookup_value VALUES ('US','SALES','ALL','ALL')

INSERT INTO lookup_value VALUES ('US','OPERATIONS','P0044','ACKNOELEDGE')

INSERT INTO lookup_value VALUES ('US','OPERATIONS','ALL', 'ALL')


SELECT *
  FROM lookup_value
 WHERE country = 'US'
   AND department = 'SALES'
   AND problem_code = DECODE (:problem, problem_code, :problem, 'ALL')
   AND disposition = DECODE (:disp, disposition, :disp, 'ALL')
```

If I run the above query passing problem_code = P0044 and disposition = 'EXCHANGE', it returns me 3 rows, where as I need only one.

```
COUNTRY DEPARTMENT  PROBLEM_CODE    DISPOSITION
-----------------------------------------------------------
US  SALES   P0044   EXCHANGE
US  SALES   ALL EXCHANGE
US  SALES   ALL ALL
```

Regards
Tauseef